# Whatsapp doesn't show login screen once registered

Tags: android, sqlite, process, android-service, whatsapp

Once you registered with the Whatsapp , even if you force close the app from App Manager or Kill its process, when you run it again it runs from the point (activity) where you left.
How does that possible? 
An Android application shows the first activity which is also set as launcher activity,
Is that possible that it saves some data in SQLite , some check or flag?

Comment: Instead of saving the instance state on close, save the instance state yourself on create. Upon starting you can determine what to show.

Comment: @NiekHaarman save the state in DB?

Comment: Wherever. It doesn't matter, perhaps SharedPreferences is easiest to manage.

Comment: @NiekHaarman when we save state, it means saving the name of the last activity being used?

Comment: Could be. Maybe some other states of views. Whatever you want. You will have to write the logic yourself, so everything is possible.

Comment: @NiekHaarman I understand , just looking for some built in methods may be if available. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startupactivity.java is your launcher activity in manifest file.

In your startupactivity.java

**1)how to check if already login or not?**

->use sharedpreferences to  check login or not(store and retrieve sharedpreferences)

->use file to store login data

->use sqlite database to store registration info.

---

->check if already register then call homescreen.java

or

**->if not registered then call registration.java**